# Tracking FindRoot errors in NestWhileList and Table

Tags: equation-solving

I'm solving many systems of two equations by varying the initial parameters. I'm running `FindRoot` in a  `NestWhileList`  where the `NestWhileList` counter allows me to alter parameter values and feed in current solutions as the start point for the next system. My `NestWhileList` index runs up to 5000 and when I run it I get 8 or 9 error messages, so far of two kinds. They  are

```
line search decreased step size to within tolerance...

General::stop: "Further output of FindRoot will be suppressed during this calculation."
```

Now I'd like to know for which `NestWhileList` index was the error generated.

This is a minimal working example similar to the code that I am running. In this example, I start with a start  point `sol` and look for solutions. Then the counter increases, the new start point `sol` is the previous solution +  the increment from the previous start point: `add`. The list `d` is some vector of parameter values.

```
d = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
sol = {0, 0};
add = {0.5, 0.5}
counter = 5;

data = NestWhileList[{#[[1]] + 1,{x, y} = {x, y} /.FindRoot[{x + y == #[[1]]*#[[1]], x- y == d[[#[[1]]]]}, {x, #[[2]][[1]] + #[[3]]  [[1]]}, {y, \#[[2]][[2]] + #[[3]][[2]]}],{x - #[[2]][[1]], y - #[[2]][[2]]}} &,{1, sol, add},Not[2 < #[[2]][[2]] < #[[2]][[1]] < 3] &, 2, counter]
```

Of course, this simple example gives no errors. I'd love to be able to figure out which index is  (or which all indices are)  generating errors so I can go look it up individually in detail and see if the error is because a solution doesn't exist or it does exist but my output is not that solution or maybe everything is fine and I can ignore the messages. I'd love it if you can tell me how this `NestWhileList` error tracker can be extended to a `Table` setting.

Comment: Did you check `Check[]`?

Comment: Thanks belisarius. I wasnt aware of `Check`. Now I am looking at `Check` and `CheckAbort` to see if I can implement it with `NestWhileList` in a productive way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `Reap/Sow` and `Check` using a modified version of the OP's example:

```
counter = 50;
d = ConstantArray[0, {counter}];
sol = {0, 0};
add = {0.5, 0.5};

data = Reap[ NestWhileList[{#[[1]] +  1, {x, y} = {x, y} /. 
   Check[FindRoot[{x + y == #[[1]]*#[[1]],  x - 4 y ==  d[[#[[1]]]]}, 
     {x, #[[2]][[1]] + #[[3]][[1]]}, {y, #[[2]][[2]] + #[[3]][[2]]}], 
    Sow[{#[[1]], x, y}] -> {x, y}], 
    {x - #[[2]][[1]],  y - #[[2]][[2]]}} &, {1, sol, add}, 
   Not[2 < #[[2]][[2]] < #[[2]][[1]] < 3] &, 2, counter]]
```

[image]

To get the steps and the values of `{x,y}` where `FindRoot` issued error messages use the second part of `data`"

```
data[[2]]
(* {{{13, 115.2, 28.8}, {14, 115.2, 28.8}, {16, 180., 45.}, {17, 180.,  45.}, 
   {18, 180., 45.}, {19, 180., 45.}, {21, 320., 80.}, {22, 320., 80.}, 
   {23, 320., 80.}, {24, 320., 80.}, {26, 500., 125.}, {27, 500., 125.},
   {28, 500., 125.}, {29, 500., 125.}, {31, 720.,  180.}, {32, 720., 180.},
   {33, 720., 180.}, {34, 720., 180.}, {36, 980., 245.}, {37, 980., 245.}, 
   {38, 980., 245.}, {39, 980.,  245.}, {41, 1280., 320.}, {42, 1280., 320.},
   {43, 1280., 320.}, {44, 1280., 320.}, {46, 1620., 405.}, {47, 1620.,  405.},
   {48, 1620., 405.}, {49, 1620., 405.}}}*)
```

Comment: Hey Kguler, that is sweet! How did you get $x+y=a^2$ and $x-4y=0$ to show errors? Also, it looks like your result jpeg might be for the case when the second equation is $x-y=0$. This is great though.. thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey Kguler, I just implemented it and it works so well. This has saved me *so much* time. I'm totally filled with gratitude. Thank you.

Comment: @Amatya, thank you for the accept. I reloaded the picture of the results I  get on my system for the input equations  $x+y=a^2$ and $x-4y=0$.

Comment: @kguler `Reap` and `Sow` might be more popular on this site +1, but I find all those torn pictures a bit overestimated.

Comment: @Artes, thanks for the upvote. (removed torn picture :))